# coloring the bar based on conditional check

Tags: javascript, css

I want to color the bars based on the conditional check.
I want to show the bar color based on the conditional check as follows:
I am displaying the 'expertise level' for the certain time period.

When the expertise column starts from 'Begining' word,  they have to show **red** color for that timeline bar.

When the expertise column starts from 'Advanced' word,  they have to show **brown** color for that timeline bar.

When the expertise column starts from 'Intermediate' word,  they have to submit **Yellow** color for that timeline bar.
Please find the complete demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/XrEgUo9oDJvxAXH03KMA?p=preview

Currently i'm using the below options:

```
function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        colors:['red','brown','yellow'],
    };
    chart.draw(dataTable,options, {
      height: (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight
    });
  }
```

Any inputs on how to give timeline chart each milestone with different colors based on the input string .

Answer (score 0):

Whatever string your using to detect what level you are at.

Use:

```
var totalWords = "foo love bar very much."; 
var firstWord =totalWords.replace(/ .*/,'');
```

To get the first word (intermediate, advanced, etc)

Then use a and if statement to output the color you want

```
  if (firstword == "advanced) {
     color = "brown";
  } else if(firstword == "intermediate"){
     color = "yellow";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly define your rows before adding them to the table so that you can iterate over them to construct an array with the corresponding colors prior or rendering the chart.

Then call map on the data array passing this function.

```
function getRowColor(row) {
  let firstWord = row[1].trim().split(' ')[0];
  if (firstWord === 'Beginning') return 'red';
  if (firstWord === 'Advanced') return 'brown';
  if (firstWord === 'Intermediate') return 'yellow';
}

const colors = rows.map(getRowColor);
```

I've forked your plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/czB6TOV0e32x71187O7S?p=preview)

Comment: I was trying to implement the same as you suggested above for https://plnkr.co/edit/67h3vWwC1SHvTlJctdkc?p=preview  and could not succeed. Any advice?

Comment: There hope I'm not doing your homework! It's just a case of adapting the function to the new data structure > https://plnkr.co/edit/yY6Cw6AxYZeEJ1FrBqlJ?p=preview

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering if you're going to accept this answer?